# Vector Assets get Distorted after importing

Tags: android, kotlin, svg

I'm trying to create a Vector Asset importing a SVG icon, but after the asset is created it is totally distorted in the previews. I've tried a few ways of importing svg, but the result is always the same, it also happens with other svg files.

[Creating the Vector Asset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2HOw.png)

[Preview of the generated asset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsvwU.png)

[Preview in a layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd9dr.png)

Here follows the generated xml:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
  <path android:pathData="M12,22A10,10 0,1 1,22 12,10.011 10.011,0 0,1 12,22ZM12,4a8,8 0,1 0,8 8A8.009,8.009 0,0 0,12 4ZM15,17L9,17L9,15L11,15L11,12L10,12L10,10h2a1,1 0,0 1,1 1v4h2v2ZM12,9.25A1.25,1.25 0,1 1,13.25 8,1.252 1.252,0 0,1 12,9.25Z" android:fillColor="#005aa5"/>
</vector>
```

Edit:
I've tested in the emulator, and the ImageView is loading the icon correctly, so it is probably a problem with the Android Studio previewing an xml drawable.

[Emulator test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBbxm.png)

Comment: You might see if there is a matching bug report in the issue tracker, and if not, file one with the original SVG and the rest of the details (e.g., Android Studio version).

Comment: @Imituiti I'm glad you solved your issue. I suggest you change your edit into an answer.  Then it would be more visible to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested in the emulator and my device, and the ImageView is loading the icon correctly, so it is probably a problem with the Android Studio previewing an xml drawable.